# Can Dirsync for Python sync files and folders in two directions

Tags: python-3.x, synchronization

I want to create a script to sync files between two directories, and was going to utilise Dirsync and Python 3 for this.

```
from dirsync import sync
sync('C:/03py/Sync/Sync1','C:/03py/Sync/Sync2','sync', twoway=True, create=True)
```

After running the file for the first time, the folders are synced. I then put a dummy file and folder into the target directory and reran the above script, hoping the file and folder would be copied back into the source directory. However I get the following:

```
Only in C:/03py/Sync/Sync2
<< TESTTWOFOLDER
<< _TESTTWOWAY.txt
```

I am not certain if I am using the above commands correctly.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this helps...

```
from dirsync import sync

source_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\first-python-app\\http'
target_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\first-python-app\\dev'

sync(target_path, source_path, 'sync', twoway=True, purge=True)
sync(source_path, target_path, 'sync')
```